# Connect tabItem to viewpager2 in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have one AlertSettingfragment which has two tabItem ( SMS text and Email). I have created two fragments for viewpager(SMStext Fragment and Email Fragment) according to the tabItem. But i am not able to connect to the viewpager. Please Help

**fragment_alertSetting.xml**

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="42dp"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/gray"
                    app:tabBackground="@drawable/track_selector"
                    app:tabGravity="fill"
                    app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
                    app:tabMode="fixed"
                    app:tabRippleColor="@color/transparent"
                    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/dark_blue"
                    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/CustomTextAppearanceTab"
                    app:tabTextColor="@color/gray_blue">

                    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                        android:id="@+id/smsTab"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/sms_text" />

                    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                        android:id="@+id/emailTab"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/email" />

                </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/alertSettingViewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="12dp"
            android:layout_marginVertical="16dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tabLayoutView" />
```

**AlertSettingFragment.kt**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class CascadeSettingsAlertFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentCascadeSettingsAlertBinding
    private var listener: OnFragmentInteractionListener? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = FragmentCascadeSettingsAlertBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false).apply {
           alertSettingViewPager.adapter = CascadeAlertSettingAdapter(this@CascadeSettingsAlertFragment)
            TabLayoutMediator(
                tabLayout,
                alertSettingViewPager
            ) { tabs, position ->
                val tabBinding = when (position) {
                    SMS_PAGE_INDEX ->  binding.smsTab
                    EMAIL_PAGE_INDEX -> binding.emailTab
                    else -> binding.smsTab
                }
                tabs.view = tabBinding.
            }.attach()

    }
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    }
```

**AlertSettingAdapter.kt**

```
const val SMS_PAGE_INDEX = 0
const val EMAIL_PAGE_INDEX = 1

class CascadeAlertSettingAdapter(fragment: Fragment) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragment) {

    private val tabFragmentsCreators: Map<Int, () -> Fragment> = mapOf(
        SMS_PAGE_INDEX to { AlertSettingsSmsFragment() },
        EMAIL_PAGE_INDEX to { AlertSettingsEmailFragment() },
    )
    override fun getItemCount() = tabFragmentsCreators.size

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return tabFragmentsCreators[position]?.invoke() ?: throw IndexOutOfBoundsException()
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the TabItems programmatically to the TabLayout, TabItems added via XML are not actually added to the TabLayout, as mentioned in the documentation of TabLayout.

More info:
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabItem